# Exponential fit and cftools give different results in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to fit an exponentially decreasing data. If I use `cftools` to fit a single term exponential, I get a good fit. However, when I try using the `fit` function:

```
f = fit(x, y, 'exp1');
```

it gives me the following error:

```
Warning: NaN, Inf, or complex value detected in startpoint;
choosing random starting point instead. 
> In curvefit.attention.Warning/throw (line 30)
  In fit>iFit (line 299)
  In fit (line 108)
```

and the coefficients it gives end up being garbage.

I thought `cftools` was running `fit` under the hood. Why is there a difference? How can I run `cftools` from the script?

Comment: It might be hard to guess without data. You *can* look at the code used by `cftool` under "File > Generate Code". It looks like one difference could be that `cftool` picks starting values for you. You can check the options on fitted models with `fitoptions(model)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do what the error suggests?

```
f = fit(x, y, 'exp1', 'StartPoint', rand);
```

you might want to change `rand` to be a more sensible first guess but that will depend entirely on your problem domain.

Otherwise `cftools` should have a [code generation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/generating-code-and-exporting-fits-to-the-workspace.html) feature that prints out the MATLAB code that replicates whatever you did interactively with the tool so you can run it programmatically in the future. This is a great way to get started.

Comment: Even when I set start points I get `f(x)=0` basically. I'll look into the code generation feature of `cftools`. Thanks.